# How to match last word in quotes in a sentence

Tags: regex

How to match last quoted word in a sentence (or first in quotes from end) and print it without quotes?

Example: `I "need" a help with "regular" expressions.`

Output: `regular`

Comment: Non greedy match pair of quotes with a negative look ahead ("no further quotes after this")

Comment: It may be helpful if you post an example of what you've already tried so we can see where it's failing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use lua programming language and in lua doesn't work, it matches first quoted word "need". How to make it to work in lua?
I used this example:
sentence = I "need" a help with "regular" expressions.
quoted = sentence:match("\"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\""), but it matches both quoted words.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?="[^"]*$)
```

([demo](http://rubular.com/r/0T2a7yB34w))

---

The regex looks like this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fxf5QiVlQk8_LxXE)

Answer (score 1):

Use a look ahead:

```
(?<=")[^"]+(?="[^"]*$)
```

which asserts the closing quote around the word is the last quote in the sentence.

The whole match is the word.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/LKTL1kodn4) of this regex working with your example sentence.

Answer (score 1):

this regex would do:

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?="[^"]*$)
```

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo 'I "need" a help with "regular" expressions.'|grep -Po '(?<=")[^"]*(?="[^"]*$)'                                                                                       
regular
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=[\w\s\"]*\")\w*(?=\"[\w\s]*\.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that there is not quote after your capture with this regex.

```
/"([^"]+)"[^"]*$/
```